# Get umbraco fields inside form view

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-contour

I need to have a custom view for an umbraco 7 form, that have a special column layout, but my problem is that I cannot output data from an umbraco field with `.GetPropertyValue("formHeader")`

I am rendering the form with

```
@Umbraco.RenderMacro("FormsRenderForm", new { FormGuid = "6189b8c2-980a-4f02-bcec-33b170020a22" })
```

Inside my Form.cshtml I would like to insert an umbraco field  `.GetPropertyValue("formHeader")`

But I cannot seem to get it to work

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
```

will return

> Error loading Partial View script (file:
>   ~/Views/MacroPartials/InsertUmbracoForm.cshtml)

Is this even possible, the way I am thinking about it ?

I am using Umbraco Forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `UmbracoTemplatePage` will work because `FormViewModel` doesn't inherit from `Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel`.  Try using `UmbracoViewPage<T>` in your Form.cshtml instead:

```
@inherits UmbracoViewPage<Umbraco.Forms.Mvc.Models.FormViewModel>
```

You can then use the `UmbracoHelper` to retrieve the currently assigned content item:

```
var currentPage = Umbraco.AssignedContentItem;
```

This will give you the current page as `IPublishedContent` so you can fetch the field values as normal.

```
var formHeader = currentPage.GetPropertyValue("formHeader");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check app_data/Logs/UmbracoTraceLog.txt what is the problem in your partial view.